# CSS background syntax

Tags: html, css, web, visual-web-developer

I've seen an curious code example.
I don't know completely what `center center / cover` means. 
`center center` means **center the background** 
`cover` means **adjust the background to the area** 
But what does `center center / cover` mean?

```
background {transparent url(...) no-repeat scroll center center / cover;}
```

Comment: Just look at the [MDN page for `background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background). _`<bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box>{1,2}`_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background

> `<bg-size>`
>   See background-size. This property must be specified after `<position>`, separated
>   with the '/' character.

i.e. it just seperates the background size from the position

Answer (score 0):

well, center center can only be specified in the background-position property so that is the background position and cover can only be specified in the background-size property so that is background-size,

these values only specify the size or position of the background-image used. Its a shorthand way of specifying all the properties and their values of the background property in one line. the forward slash is when you want to specify the position and the size.

for example:

```
background: colour url(...) position/size repeat clip origin attachment;
```

an example where sizes are used:

```
background: colour url(..) 50px(left-margin) 50px(top-margin)/50%(size) no-repeat scroll;
```